# Dill.detect.children object types

Tags: python, pickle, dill

`Dill.detect.children` requires two arguments; `obj` and `objtype`.

Inspecting an *audiofile* object I can call:

```
dill.detect.children(audiofile, object)
dill.detect.children(audiofile, dict)
dill.detect.children(audiofile, list)
```

Which return without error.

But how about looking for instance methods?

```
type(audiofile.save)
```

returns

```
instancemethod
```

Tried

```
dill.detect.children(audiofile, instancemethod)
```

which returns

```
NameError: name 'instancemethod' is not defined
```

Tried

```
dill.detect.children(audiofile, 'instancemethod')
```

which returns

```
TypeError: isinstance() arg 2 must be a class, type, or tuple of classes and types
```

Shouldn't this return similar results to calling `dir(audiofile)`?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`types.MethodType`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.MethodType):

> **types.MethodType**
>
> The type of methods of user-defined class instances.

```
>>> import types
>>> print types.MethodType
<type 'instancemethod'>
>>> p = Process()
>>> type(p.start) == types.MethodType
True
```

However, I don't think `dill.detect.children` does what you think it does. Its docstring says:

```
children(obj, objtype, depth=1, ignore=())
    Find the chain of referrers for obj. Chain will start with obj.

    objtype: an object type or tuple of types to search for
    depth: search depth (e.g. depth=2 is 'grandparents')
    ignore: an object or tuple of objects to ignore in the search

    NOTE: a common thing to ignore is all globals, 'ignore=globals()'

    NOTE: repeated calls may yield different results, as python stores
    the last value in the special variable '_'; thus, it is often good
    to execute something to replace '_' (e.g. >>> 1+1).
```

This is not the same as "find all attributes on `obj` that match type `objtype`", which it at least appears is what you're expecting it to do.

Comment: oh yes. had played around with the types module earlier.

Comment: your reference is how I read "an object type or tuple of types to search for", but is it meant in fact to return any objects of object type within the chain of referrers?

Comment: @MikeiLL Right. So, if you put `audiofile` in a list, and then called `dill.detect.children(audiofile, list)`, you'd get a reference to that list back. If you use `dict`, you get a reference to the `globals()` dict back.

Comment: I'm not understanding what `types.MethodType` does, aside from returning either the word `instancemethod` or the type(?) `<type 'instancemethod'>`

Comment: @MikeiLL I was just explaining the correct way to get a reference to the `instancemethod` type object. In reality, it's probably not useful here, since an instancemethod object is unlikely to have a reference to your `audiofile` object.

Comment: So if I put `audiofile` in a list, then the `list` is one of the *children* (referrers) of the `audiofile` object? And if I put that `list` in another `list` the second list is a child (referrer) of `audiofile` at depth 2 aka a *grandchild* of `audiofile`?